# Issue with Rails Content_for / yield - duplicated content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yield, content-for

I'm trying to load some javascript in my application page using a named yield block, but the code is duplicated because of a generic yield that load my view pages. something like that:

-----Code present in views-----

```
<% content_for :bottom_scripts do %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
             Some Javascripts
    </script>
<% end %>
```

------Code in my application page-----

```
<div id = "body">
    <%= yield %>
</div>
<%= yield :bottom_scripts %>
```

---

The script code is printed twice, but I need it just printed in the second yield, any thoughts?

Comment: is it printed once in the body and once outside? can you post a sample of the rendered page?

Comment: As a side note, I would suggest leaving the script tags outside the yield instead of creating multiple instances for each content_for :bottom_scripts.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `content_for` in your layout instead of yield

when `content_for` is not passed a block it outputs the block stored at that identifier

in view:

```
<% content_for :foo do %>
   <p>Bar</p>
<% end %>
```

in layout:

```
<%= content_for :foo %>
```

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for